# How to convert WSDL file to Xml in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, xml, wsdl

My manager told me that .NET Framework 4.0 provide the utility to convert WSDL file to XML. After Googling hours I could not find anything related it. Is it possible in .NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: WSDL is an XML-based format. So a WSDL file is already XML. It's unclear (to me) what task you're actually trying to perform.

Comment: Actually we want to covert a wsdl file to an xml request.